# Unable to execute stored procedures through OLEDB

Tags: c++, database, oracle, stored-procedures, oledb

I'm locally running an instance of Oracle 11gR2 for testing.  I'm connecting to it with OLEDB using VC++.  I use CCommand and I'm able to select, update, insert and delete from my tables.
What I can't do right now is execute stored procedures.

It is a simple stored procedure that inserts a row to my table. I can run it from SQL Plus without a hitch. However, when I come to execute it from my code, it doesn't work.  I get a 80040e14 error.

It's pretty straightforward, but here is the line anyway.

```
hr = cmd.Open(session, "exec get_item_count");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXEC` is SQL*Plus syntax.  It is not valid outside SQL*Plus (and a variety of PL/SQL GUIs that implement many of the features SQL*Plus provides).

You probably want something like this (using ODBC syntax)

```
hr = cmd.Open(session, "{call get_item_count}");
```

or this (using Oracle syntax)

```
hr = cmd.Open(session, "begin get_item_count; end;");
```

If you use the Oracle syntax, the same syntax will work both in SQL*Plus and from your application.  SQL*Plus does not understand ODBC syntax.  However, other OLE DB providers will support ODBC syntax so ODBC syntax is portable across different database engines.

Additionally, if you have a PL/SQL object that retrieves an item count, that should be a stored function not a stored procedure.  You say that the procedure is inserting a row into your table, which is something that a procedure should do and a function should not, but the name of the object `get_item_count` doesn't seem to match your description of what it is doing.

Comment: Thank you so much I was going insane.  As for the procedure name, it does do what I said it did, it's purpose was switched around as I was trying stuff out; however I forgot to change it's name here for clarity.